# How to wait for a shell script reboot in Fabric 2

Tags: python, fabric

I'm using Fabric 2 and I'm trying to run a shell script on a number of hosts sequentially. In the script, it configures a few settings and reboots that host. When I run my task however it ends after the script has run on the first host (I'm guessing because the SSH connection terminates due to the reboot). I tried looking into setting 'warn_only' to True, but I don't see where to set this value on Fabric 2.

Adding:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
```

throws a "NameError: global name 'settings' is not defined" error.

Is there a correct format to warn_only? If not possible yet in Fabric 2, is there a way to continue running my task regardless of this reboot?

My script:

```
from fabric import *
import time
import csv

@task
def test(ctx):

    hosts = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']

    for host in hosts:
        c = Connection(host=host, user="user", connect_kwargs={"password": "password"})

        c.run("./shell_script.sh")

        configured = False

        while not configured:
            result = c.run("cat /etc/hostname")
            if result != "default": configured = True
            time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

So a workaround has been to run the task with the -w flag which will enable warn_only and give me the desired functionality. It would be more preferable to be able to set this property in the code though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the `config` argument to the connection class instead of the `with settings()` construction, and `warn_only` as been renamed to `warn`;

```py
with Connection(host=host, user="user", connect_kwargs={"password": "password"}) as c:
    c.run("./shell_script.sh", warn=True)
```

More generally, you can get upgrade documentation at https://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#run